# How can I get the product permalink on the WooCommerce shop page?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, permalinks

I have tried several times to get the product permalink on the WooCommerce shop page, but I have a strange problem, the link appears in the Elementor editor, but not on the shop page.

```
protected function render() {

    $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();
    $button_text = $settings['button_text'];

    global $product;

    $link = get_permalink( $product->ID );
    
    echo $link;
}
```

[image]

[image]